# vector push_back doesn't work

Tags: c++

I created a very simple code, but the push_back function doesn't want to work. It gives me an absolutely different result than expected.

Here is the code:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::ifstream infile ("words.txt");
std::string temp;
while (std::getline(infile, temp))
{
    words.push_back(temp);
}
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << words[i] << " ";
}
```

The "words.txt" file contains only 4 words:

```
window
tyre
give
speaker
```

The result is supposed to be "window tyre give speaker", but for me it is " speaker".
What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you're reading _correct_ file ?

Comment: Have you tried dumping the input file (e.g. with `hexdump -C` or similar) to check for rogue control sequences such as `\r` which might explain the behaviour which you are seeing. (Your input file might be a text file from a DOS/Windows like system and you might be using a unix-like system.)

Comment: yes, i'm. I tried to edit it, but I always get the last word.

Comment: Check with `std::getline(infile, temp,'\r')`

Comment: I'd also guess a wrong end-line character sequence. Did you step through your program using a debugger, check the `while` loop's behavior.

Comment: Try to print the words using `std::cout << words[i] << "\n";`, i.e., use `"\n"` instead of `" "` as a separator.

Comment: thank you very much :) the '\r' caused the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proved to be the underlying problem:

Have you tried dumping the input file (e.g. with `hexdump -C` or similar) to check for rogue control sequences such as `\r` which might explain the behaviour which you are seeing.

Your input file might be a text file from a DOS/Windows-like system and you might be using a Unix-like system.